# Grey Screen VNC Ubuntu 22.04 KDE on Raspberrypi

Tags: ubuntu, kde-plasma, vnc-server, tightvnc

I installed ubuntu on my raspberry and i currently have access via ssh.
My goal is to install the KDE desktop (I did) and connect via VNC.

I followed this guide here (but I installed TightVNC):
[LINK](https://bytexd.com/how-to-install-configure-vnc-server-on-ubuntu/)

it's strange because the desktop is all gray but if I do crtl + alt + del it shows me the screen:
[image: KDE grey screen]

[image: KDE ctrl+alt+del]

So I have TigerVNC, KDE and Ubuntu 22.04.
I tried connecting with both TightVNC Viewer and VNCViewew.

~/.vnc/xstartup

```
#!/bin/sh

#Start up the standard system desktop
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRES

/usr/bin/startplasma-x11

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r &HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
x-window-manager &
```

~/.vnc/tomOS:1.log

```
06/10/22 21:01:13 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
06/10/22 21:01:13 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
06/10/22 21:01:13 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
06/10/22 21:01:13 All Rights Reserved.
06/10/22 21:01:13 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
06/10/22 21:01:13 Desktop name 'X' (tomOS:1)
06/10/22 21:01:13 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
06/10/22 21:01:13 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is SplashApp(0xfffff49c5f18), parent's thread is QThread(0xaaaaed6ce3a0), current thread is QThread(0xaaaaeda3b7c0)
QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
qt.qpa.xcb: xrender >= 0.5 required to create pixmap cursors
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 355, resource id: 32, major code: 53 (CreatePixmap), minor code: 0
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 356, resource id: 8388619, major code: 55 (CreateGC), minor code: 0
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 357, resource id: 8388619, major code: 55 (CreateGC), minor code: 0
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/klauncher'
kdeinit5: Launched KLauncher, pid = 4261, result = 0
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
kdeinit5: opened connection to :1
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
Initializing  "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_mouse.so"
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
kdeinit5: Got SETENV 'XCURSOR_THEME=breeze_cursors' from launcher.
kdeinit5: Got SETENV 'XCURSOR_SIZE=24' from launcher.
Initializing  "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_fonts.so"
Initializing  "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_style.so"
kdeinit5: Got SETENV 'GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/tom/.gtkrc:/home/tom/.config/gtkrc' from launcher.
kdeinit5: Got SETENV 'GTK2_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/tom/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/tom/.config/gtkrc-2.0' from launcher.
QDBusConnection: error: could not send signal to service "" path "//home/tom/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals" interface "org.kde.kconfig.notify" member "ConfigChanged": Invalid object path: //home/tom/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals
org.kde.plasma.session: process job  "kcminit_startup" finished with exit code  0
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
xsettingsd: Loaded 0 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Created window 0x2000001 on screen 0 with timestamp 2930536207
xsettingsd: Selection _XSETTINGS_S0 is owned by 0x0
xsettingsd: Took ownership of selection _XSETTINGS_S0
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
Warning: Setting a new default format with a different version or profile after the global shared context is created may cause issues with context sharing.
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
Xlib:  extension "MIT-SCREEN-SAVER" missing on display ":1".
kdeinit5: Got SETENV 'SESSION_MANAGER=local/tomOS:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/4304,unix/tomOS:/tmp/.ICE-unix/4304' from launcher.
org.kde.libkbolt: Failed to connect to Bolt manager DBus interface: 
org.kde.bolt.kded: Couldn't connect to Bolt DBus daemon
kdeinit5: Got SETENV 'SESSION_MANAGER=local/tomOS:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/4304,unix/tomOS:/tmp/.ICE-unix/4304' from launcher.
print-manager.kded: unable to register service to dbus
Initializing  "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_kgamma.so"
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1.desktop" ("/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libexec/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1")
Installing the delayed initialization callback.
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.plasmashell.desktop" ("/usr/bin/plasmashell")
Initializing  "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_touchpad.so"
kcm_touchpad: Using X11 backend
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/pam_kwallet_init.desktop" ("/usr/share/libpam-kwallet-common/pam_kwallet_init")
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/baloo_file.desktop" ("/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libexec/baloo_file")
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/powerdevil.desktop" ("/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libexec/org_kde_powerdevil")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/kaccess.desktop" ("/usr/bin/kaccess")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/xembedsniproxy.desktop" ("/usr/bin/xembedsniproxy")
org.kde.kcm_keyboard: Failed to fetch layouts from server: Wrong property format
org.kde.kcm_keyboard: Failed to get layout groups from X server
Baloo File Indexing has been disabled
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.discover.notifier.desktop" ("/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libexec/DiscoverNotifier")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/pulseaudio.desktop" ("/usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/xdg-user-dirs.desktop" ("/usr/bin/xdg-user-dirs-update")
org.kde.kcm_keyboard: X server XKB extension  0 . 0  !=  1 . 0
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/gmenudbusmenuproxy.desktop" ("/usr/bin/gmenudbusmenuproxy")
Xlib XKB extension major= 1  minor= 0
kf.bluezqt: Cannot open /dev/rfkill for writing!
kcm_touchpad: Using X11 backend
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop" ("/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libexec/kdeconnectd")
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
AUDIT: Thu Oct  6 21:01:21 2022: 4216 Xtightvnc: client 15 rejected from local host
Failure: Module initialization failed
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/spice-vdagent.desktop" ("/usr/bin/spice-vdagent")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-shell-overrides-migration.desktop" ("/usr/libexec/gnome-shell-overrides-migration.sh")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/snap-userd-autostart.desktop" ("/usr/bin/snap", "userd", "--autostart")
New PolkitAgentListener  0xaaaab7af1600
Adding new listener  PolkitQt1::Agent::Listener(0xaaaab7b17640) for  0xaaaab7af1600
Listener online
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntu-advantage-notification.desktop" ("/usr/lib/update-notifier/ubuntu-advantage-notification")
Authentication agent result: true
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/geoclue-demo-agent.desktop" ("/usr/libexec/geoclue-2.0/demos/agent")
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntu-report-on-upgrade.desktop" ("/usr/bin/ubuntu-report", "send", "upgrade")
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop" ("/usr/libexec/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-notify")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.DejaDup.Monitor.desktop" ("/usr/libexec/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor")
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
Geolocation service not in use
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/kup-daemon.desktop" ("/usr/bin/kup-daemon")
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop" ("/usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher", "--launch-immediately")
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/im-launch.desktop" ("/usr/bin/sh", "-c", "if [ \"x$XDG_SESSION_TYPE\" = \"xwayland\" ] ; then exec env IM_CONFIG_CHECK_ENV=1 im-launch true; fi")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.korgac.desktop" ("/usr/bin/korgac")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-miner-fs-3.desktop" ("/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3")
kde.xembedsniproxy: could not load damage extension. Quitting
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
X server has not matching XKB extension 

Delayed initialization.
Reloading the khotkeys configuration
Version 2 File!
Loaded defaults from "/usr/share/khotkeys/defaults.khotkeys"
true
Imported file "/usr/share/khotkeys/defaults.khotkeys"
Version 2 File!
The X11 connection broke: Unsupported extension used (code 2)
XIO:  fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server ":1"
      after 319 requests (319 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
org.kde.powerdevil: org.kde.powerdevil.discretegpuhelper.hasdualgpu failed
org.kde.powerdevil: org.kde.powerdevil.chargethresholdhelper.getthreshold failed ""
org.kde.powerdevil: org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper.brightness failed
kup.daemon: "Kup is not enabled, enable it from the system settings module. You can do that by running kcmshell5 kup"
kf.notifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 543, resource id: 54525957, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
kwin_platform_x11_standalone: Compositing disabled: no composite extension available
kwin_core: Compositing is not possible
Aborting shell load: The activity manager daemon (kactivitymanagerd) is not running.
If this Plasma has been installed into a custom prefix, verify that its D-Bus services dir is known to the system for the daemon to be activatable.
org.kde.powerdevil: DPMS extension not available
kf.notifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
org.kde.powerdevil: Handle button events action could not check for screen configuration
org.kde.powerdevil: The profile  "AC" tried to activate "DimDisplay" a non-existent action. This is usually due to an installation problem, a configuration problem, or because the action is not supported
org.kde.powerdevil: The profile  "AC" tried to activate "DPMSControl" a non-existent action. This is usually due to an installation problem, a configuration problem, or because the action is not supported
org.kde.powerdevil: org.kde.powerdevil.chargethresholdhelper.getthreshold failed ""
org.kde.kscreen: Failed to request backend: unknown error
org.kde.powerdevil: Handle button events action could not check for screen configuration
QObject::connect(QObject, ConfigMonitor::Private): invalid nullptr parameter
org.kde.kscreen: Failed to request backend: unknown error
kwin_core: Failed to update gamma ramp for output KWin::X11PlaceholderOutput(0xaaaab4cca450, name="Placeholder-0", geometry=QRect(0,0 1024x768), scale=1)
Aborting shell load: The activity manager daemon (kactivitymanagerd) is not running.
If this Plasma has been installed into a custom prefix, verify that its D-Bus services dir is known to the system for the daemon to be activatable.
kf.plasma.quick: Applet preload policy set to 1
qml: PlasmaExtras.ScrollArea is deprecated. Use PlasmaComponents3.ScrollView instead.
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:118:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:118:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
The X11 connection broke: Unsupported extension used (code 2)
XIO:  fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server ":1"
      after 492 requests (456 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 781, resource id: 75497478, major code: 15 (QueryTree), minor code: 0

(tracker-miner-fs-3:4390): Tracker-CRITICAL **: 21:01:26.811: Could not request DBus name 'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files': D-Bus service name:'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files' is already taken, perhaps the application is already running?
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 0 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 0 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
xsettingsd: Reloading configuration
xsettingsd: Loaded 11 settings from /home/tom/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf
kf.notifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
kf.notifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
kf.notifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
kf.notifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 828, resource id: 8388622, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
kdeconnect.core: Could not query capabilities from notifications server

06/10/22 21:02:05 Got connection from client 192.168.1.70
06/10/22 21:02:05 Using protocol version 3.8
06/10/22 21:02:05 Full-control authentication passed by 192.168.1.70
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 24
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
06/10/22 21:02:05 Using zlib encoding for client 192.168.1.70
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
06/10/22 21:02:05 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.1.70
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
06/10/22 21:02:05 Pixel format for client 192.168.1.70:
06/10/22 21:02:05   8 bpp, depth 6
06/10/22 21:02:05   true colour: max r 3 g 3 b 3, shift r 4 g 2 b 0
06/10/22 21:02:05 Using raw encoding for client 192.168.1.70
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 24
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
06/10/22 21:02:05 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.1.70
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 24
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
06/10/22 21:02:05 Using zlib encoding for client 192.168.1.70
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
06/10/22 21:02:05 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.1.70
06/10/22 21:02:05 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
06/10/22 21:02:05 Pixel format for client 192.168.1.70:
06/10/22 21:02:05   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
06/10/22 21:02:05   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
06/10/22 21:02:05   no translation needed
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
kdeinit5: Fatal IO error: client killed
kdeinit5: sending SIGHUP to children.
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
klauncher: Exiting on signal 1
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = ksmserver path = /usr/bin pid = 4304
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/ksmserver 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi
kdeinit5: sending SIGTERM to children.
kdeinit5: Exit.
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 7 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 8 and type 'Read', disabling...
Could not fully finish the process "/usr/bin/plasma_session"
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :1
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

kdeinit5_wrapper: Warning: connect(/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__1) failed: : No such file or directory
Error: Can not contact kdeinit5!
"kdeinit5_shutdown" () exited with code 255
startkde: Starting up...
startkde: Shutting down...
startkde: Done.
/home/tom/.vnc/xstartup: 10: [: missing ]
/home/tom/.vnc/xstartup: 10: HOME/.Xresources: not found
xsetroot:  unable to open display ':1'

(x-window-manager:4542): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:02:12.404: cannot open display: :1
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libexec/org_kde_powerdevil
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = org_kde_powerdevil path = /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libexec pid = 4320
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libexec/org_kde_powerdevil 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :1
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :1
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Unable to start Dr. Konqi
Re-raising signal for core dump handling.
Unable to start Dr. Konqi
Re-raising signal for core dump handling.
```

/etc/gdm3/custom.conf

```
# GDM configuration storage
#
# See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false

# Enabling automatic login
#  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
#  AutomaticLogin = user1

# Enabling timed login
#  TimedLoginEnable = true
#  TimedLogin = user1
#  TimedLoginDelay = 10

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
#Enable=true
```

sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager

```
Sono disponibili 4 scelte per l'alternativa x-session-manager (che fornisce /usr/bin/x-session-manager).

  Selezione    Percorso                  Priorità  Stato
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/gnome-session     50        modalità automatica
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-session     50        modalità manuale
* 2            /usr/bin/startplasma-x11   40        modalità manuale
  3            /usr/bin/startxfce4        50        modalità manuale
  4            /usr/bin/xfce4-session     40        modalità manuale
```

I hope there are enough elements to find the problem :/